# Using PNG (which updates) as a source for an RTMP live stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp

I've been googling a lot lately trying but I have yet to find a solution.

I've been using OBS to stream some textual data, where it grabs some data from a webpage and dynamically updates. This is easy, but involves way more overhead and CPU usage than I want. So cue up the command line and FFMPEG. I've gotten a script that'll update this textual information for me and save as a PNG. It updates every 10 seconds. The PNG file is 1280x720.

All I want on my RTMP stream is this image (with audio). But I can't figure out how to use ***only*** a PNG as the source of a video stream.

This does NOT work:
`ffmpeg -re -y -framerate 1 -loop 1 -f image2 -i "./image.png" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset fast -r 30 -g 120 -b:v 1000k -bufsize 512k -f flv "rtmps://mydomain.com/endpoint"`
This just stalls. The encode time goes nowhere and the frame counter hardly moves.

I want this to be compatible with Facebook Live, so I need the output to be 30 fps with GOPs every few seconds.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I *could* use an overlay, but I'd prefer not to.

Thanks!